# How to implement the following?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**Given:**

- 6 activities. (A, B, C, D, E, F)
- Each activity consists of several edittexts or a camera implementation and a next button to goto next activity (The activity which is going to be opened depends on the value entered by the user).
- If edittexts are displayable or not comes from the server.
- Incase there are no edittexts on the layout then only next button is shown.

**Flow of the application:** `A->B->C(->D)->E->F`

The Activity D opens only when a certain condition is met in activity C.

**Todo:**

- Incase, The activity contains no edittext and only next button i should be able to skip this activity.
- If the flow of my application is like: `A->B->C->E->F` Then when i press hard back the flow should be `F->E->C->B->A`
- If the flow of my application is like: `A->B->C->D->E->F` Then when i press hard back the flow should be `F->E->C->B->A`
- If the flow of my application is like: `A->C->D->E->F` Here we skipped B because there are no views in Activity B, When i press hard back the flow should be F->E->C->A

**what i did:**

- To skip the activity when no fields are available inside onCreate(), I am checking if any field is displayable if no then i add the activity name in a stack if it is not present in it and then open the next activity.

  ```
  // Block for skipping this screen
  if (skipScreen) {
      Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
  } else {
      if (!Constants.st.contains(B.class)) {
          Constants.st.push(B.class);
      }
  }
  ```
- And when i press back from an activity i pop() the name of that activity from the stack and peek() at the top of the stack and jump to that activity.

  ```
  public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();

      Constants.st.pop();
      Intent i = null;
      if (Constants.st.isEmpty()) {
             i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
      } else {
              Class<Activity> jumpTo = Constants.st.peek();
              i = new Intent(B.this, jumpTo);
      }
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
  }
  ```

Comment: Haha.. Thats well explained.. have you though about of using fragment instead of activity.then what you load on the activity as fragment will only u get on back pressed so you don't have to do the headache to do what you intend to do... or what you can do is use ObserverPattern.. good to see someone from nagpur

Comment: thanks, but the implementation is already done using activity and i don't think i will be allowed to re-implement it, btw i am living in mumbai now. also r u from nagpur ?

Comment: ya... then check for ObserverPattern for your implementation

Comment: I am studying it at the moment, but can you please show an example of the above problems solution. (^_^)

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [statePattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) will be very helpfull. [Here](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) is a short tutorial.

Comment: Its interesting i am studying it now, at the same time can you please give an example solution for above problem.